# What is the name of a bipartite graph with edges also allowed on one side

Tags: graph-theory

In the bipartite graph we have two sides $A$, $B$ with edges allowed only between $A$ and $B$.

Is there a name for such a graph where we are also permitted to have edges from $A$ to $A$ (but not from $B$ to $B$)? I tried searching for "semi bipartite graph" but found no results.

Comment: Isn't any graph trivially one of these, if $B$ contains just a single element? You might need additional constraints to turn this into an interesting concept.

Comment: Doesn't fully answer your question, but FYI B is called an independent set.

Comment: kviiri, yes, provided of course at least one vertex that is not the endpoint of a loop. (I suppose one could just take $B = \varnothing$.)

Comment: Yes. The word  you're looking for is "graph". (If $G=(V,E)$ is a graph, let $A=V$ and $B=\emptyset$.)